# $\sin x= \cos y=0,$ Find a relation between $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, roots, trigonometric-integrals

$\sin x= \cos y=0,$ Find a relation between $x$ and $y$ for $x\neq y$.

My try-

$\sin x=0$ gives x= n$\pi$

$\cos y=0$ gives $y=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\sin x=\cos y$ gives

$sin x=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-y)$ i.e.

$x=m\pi+(-1)^m(\frac{\pi}{2}-y)$

After this i am stuck.

Comment: If you have already established that $\sin x=0$ and $\cos y=0$, then solving $\sin x=\cos y$ is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin x=0$ and $\cos y=0$ the we automatically have $\sin x =\cos y$. The answer is $x=n\pi$ and $y=\frac {(2m+1)\pi} 2$ where $n$ and $m$ are integers.

For the edited version of the question you can say that $\frac x {\pi} $ is a rational multiple of $\frac y {\pi} -\frac 1  2$. Equivalently, $x$ is a rational multiple of $y-\frac {\pi} 2$.

Comment: I want a relation between x and y.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Finding the general solution for $x$ and $y$ does not mean you have to find a relation between $x$ and $y$. @ananditakumari

Comment: I have edited the question. Actually i need a relation between x and y.

Comment: $x-y = (k_1 +\frac12)\pi$ and $x+y = (k_2 +\frac12)\pi$ and $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{2k_3}{2k_4+1}$ where $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ are integers but these are less informative

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sin x=0 \iff x=k\pi \quad k\in \mathbb Z$$

$$\cos y=0 \iff y=\frac\pi 2+h\pi\quad h\in \mathbb Z$$

therefore

$$y=x+\frac \pi 2 +j\pi\quad j\in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: How did you get the last step?

Comment: @ananditakumari Since $h\pi =(k+j)\pi$ for some $j$ we can conclude in that way.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin x=\cos y=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-y)=0$$
We know that $\sin x=0$ gives $x=n\pi$ but this includes a solution of $x=0$ so we have
$$x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}-y=\frac{2n\pi+\pi}{2}-y=\pi(\frac{2n+1}{2})-y$$
where $n\in\mathbb Z$. Hope that helps.